# Finding the best statistical significant test

Tags: testing, statistics

I am trying to find the model that gives the maximum performance among two models. For that, what is the best statistical significant test, can be used to compare two independent models having ordinal data?

I found that Mann-Whitney U test is suitable for this. Is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As written, this question appears to be asking for general statistics advice; it may more appropriate for Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Questions here must be about a specific programming problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Stack%20Overflow%20only%20accepts%20certain,it%20will%20likely%20be%20closed.). Please adjust your question according to the recommendations at the link or it may be closed.